# Embedding LinkedIn company updates / feeds

Tags: linkedin-api, feed, linkedin-jsapi

We have created a SharePoint 2010 web part where we display our company feed from `https://www.linkedin.com/company/"Name of Company"/`.

End-users need to login the first time (that is ok). But even though they login using their personal LinkedIn profile, they cannot see our company-feed. Why is that?

If the users are set as LinkedIn Designated Admins they can see the feed, otherwise they cannot.

We are using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: "The key"
lang: da_DK
authorize: true
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
```

I hope someone can share their knowledge.

Comment: have you find any solution for this.

Comment: No :) and LinkedIn support can't help

Comment: Do you have similar issue?

Comment: yes I am getting 403 when fetching updates. lack of documentation :(

Answer (score 2):

This is why :'( https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

> Starting on May 12, 2015, we will be limiting the open APIs to only support the following uses:
>
> - Allowing members to represent their professional identity via their LinkedIn profile using our Profile API.
> - Enabling members to post certifications directly to their LinkedIn profile with our Add to Profile tools.
> - Enabling members to share professional content to their LinkedIn network from across the Web leveraging our Share API.
> - Enabling companies to share professional content to LinkedIn with our Company API.

Only people who can admin the feed can read/update to the company feed. All others are excluded unless you manage to get yourself promoted to LinkedIN partner: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Answer (score 2):

Some light on this issue over here:

As ahmeij said, Linkedin doesnt provide anymore an easy way of embedding your company/personal profile timeline anywhere. However, there is an alternative way of implementing this.

You will make use of the RSS feed of the profile. The url will be something like this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/biz/[PROFILE ID]/feed?start=0&v2=true
```

You can find out the numeric ID in you profile/company page.

[Read the full source here: https://www.glintech.com/blog/confluence-embed-linkedin-company-feed.html](https://www.glintech.com/blog/confluence-embed-linkedin-company-feed.html)

Comment: Please ignore this solution. It won't work due to the CORSS policy from linkedin side

Comment: Ignore? It might not work if you are directly calling this from the front-end Javascript. But you can easily call this in the back-end, and create your own AJAX call to return this response from the backend, and embed that. Nothing is 100% perfect, but this is a crude, but good workaround.

Comment: Happy that it worked for you ;) By the way, how do you get this data from back end? just doing a http request? thanks

Comment: I realized that You can use a PHP cors proxy, however, the link doesnt work anymore

Comment: @HenleyChiu Is there a GUI service to do this somewhere?

Comment: I tried a couple of request and didt work... therefore, I think this hack is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to implement a CORS proxy, and got this working. 
I used this simple [PHP CORS proxy](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy)

However, LinkedIn site doesn't return any information from this URL anymore, it just returns a [301 - moved permanently] error :_(

Comment: sorry I am not following this implementation anymore, therefore, I cant answer u

Answer (score 0):

As Alberto mentioned in the post below a RSS feed can be used to create an embed code. To enable RSS on your LinkedIn and get the RSS link you can follow [this guide](https://www.dummies.com/social-media/linkedin/how-to-use-linkedin-updates-and-rss-feeds/). Then you can use [this plugin](https://www.powr.io/plugins/rss-feed/standalone) to generate an embed code of the feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a social wall solution like [Walls.io](https://walls.io/sources/linkedin) to add LinkedIn company feeds to your Sharepoint website. The tool generates an iframe or JavaScript code that you can embed. [Here's an article on how it works on SharePoint](https://help.walls.io/en/articles/5737899-how-to-embed-a-social-feed-on-microsoft-sharepoint).